# What is the package under which IOException is defined in Java?

Tags: java, exception, ioexception

Exception and all its subclasses are defined under java.lang package.
But when the exception message for IOException is printed, unlike other exceptions, it says java.io.IOException rather than java.lang.IOException.

Why so?

Comment: Probably because `@author  unascribed` thought it would fit there better

Comment: _Exception and all its subclasses are defined under java.lang package_ ehh .. no, please check the doc :)

Answer (score 0):

A package is *not* a boundary for where classes can subclass/implement other classes or interfaces. They're merely a means to organize code that belongs together to the same "general region".

The `java.lang` package does not know about everything in the world, so it's find to have exceptions elsewhere, also in your private `com.example.acme` package. And naturally, they'd inherit/implement the subclasses/interfaces from elsewhere, be it `java.lang`, or any other package.